# is there a way to avoid the 'open save save as' dialog in ie9 by registering a mime type?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, mime-types, mime

I'm trying to bypass the 'open, save, save-as' dialog in ie9 for word perfect documents. Ideally my client wants wordperfect to pop up when a user clicks a link to a wpd doc without prompting the user. Is this possible to do this by defining a mime type?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148(v=vs.85).aspx

the above page mentions something about these registry entries but it's not clear to me weather this would solve my issue.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
     Software
          Microsoft
               Windows
                    CurrentVersion
                         InternetSettings
                              Secure Mime Handlers
HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
     Software
          Microsoft
               Windows
                    CurrentVersion
                         InternetSettings
                              Secure Mime Handlers
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending the file using a HTTP Content-Type header of `application/wordperfect`? This is the first thing IE would look for to determine how to open the file.

The link you mentioned says

> In Windows XP SP2 and later, after downloading a file, Internet Explorer consults the registry to find out which ProgID and CLSID is associated with the MIME type of the file. The browser then finds the ProgID and CLSID associated with the file name extension. If these ProgIDs do not match, and the CLSIDs do not match, Internet Explorer prompts the user before executing the file, as a safety precaution.

That is if you use Content-Type `application-wordperfect` and your file ends with `.wpd` then this would suffice to open the file automatically given WordPerfect registered itself with appropriate ProgIDs and CLSID upon installation.

You may check in your client's registry whether appropriate entries exist, the [Registry Locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Known_MimeTypes) in that link show where you would have to look for them.